# Map postgreSQL enum to Java enum with JPA (EclipseLink) and custom converter

Tags: postgresql, jpa, enums, eclipselink

I'm trying to map with JPA (`EclipseLink` provider) a postgreSQL `ENUM` type to Java enum type (and vice versa).

I know I can easily map a Java enum to a `varchar` type in my postgreSQL database with the `@Enumerated` annotation but I want to map it in a postgreSQL`ENUM` tpye. I think I must use a custom EclipseLink converter to do this.

So, I started to implement a `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter` but I don't kown how to implement the `convertObjectValueToDataValue`, the `initialize` and the `isMutable` methods...

Can someone explain me how to implement these methods please ?

For now, my class is this one :

```
public class EnumConverter implements Converter {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object object, Session session) {

    if(object instanceof PGobject){
        return LangageEnum.valueOf(LangageEnum.class, ((PGobject)object).getValue());           
    }

    return null;
}

public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object object, Session session) {
    // WHAT HERE...?
    // I tried to play with PGObject witout success...
    return object;
}

public void initialize(DatabaseMapping arg0, Session arg1) {
    // WHAT INITIALIZATION HERE...?
}

public boolean isMutable() {
    // TRUE OR FALSE AND WHY...?
    return false;
}

}

@Converter(name="langageConverter", converterClass=EnumConverter.class)
@Convert(value="langageConverter")
private LangageEnum langage;
```

Thanks for explanations, I searched for custom converters for EclipseLink with Google but this time Google was not my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I made some test with basic SELECT statement in another project and I saw that my postgreSQL `ENUM` type is returned as `PGObject` with value set to the value of my `ENUM` (in my case `FR`, `EN` or `DE`) and with type of the name of my enum.

Ex : if I create the following `ENUM` in pg :

```
CREATE TYPE langage AS ENUM ('FR', 'EN', 'DE');
```

I will receive `PGObject` with value `FR` or `EN` or `DE` and with type `langage`.

So, when I want to convert Java object to my `ENUM`, I simply create a custom EclipseLink `Converter` and return a `PGObject` like this in the `convertObjectValueToDataValue` :

```
public class EnumConverter implements Converter {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EnumConverter.class);

public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object object, Session session) {

    if(object instanceof PGobject){
        return LangageEnum.valueOf(LangageEnum.class, ((PGobject)object).getValue());           
    }

    return null;
}

public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object object, Session session) {

    if(object instanceof LangageEnum){

        PGobject pg = new PGobject();

        try {
            pg.setValue(((LangageEnum)object).name());
            pg.setType("langage");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
        }

        return pg;
    }

    return object;
}

public void initialize(DatabaseMapping dm, Session session) {
    dm.getField().setSqlType(Types.OTHER);
}

public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

}
```

and it's work great.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It probably doesn’t change much, but shouldn’t `isMutable()` return `false` for `ENUM` types?